# Most efficient way to create a string out of a list of characters then clear it

Tags: java, string, linked-list

I'm trying to create a JSON-like format to load components from files and while writing the parser I've run into an interesting performance question.

The parser reads the file character by character, so I have a LinkedList as a buffer. After reaching the end of a key (`:`) or a value (`,`) the buffer has to be emptied and a string constructed of it.

My question is what is the most efficient way to do this.

My two best bets would be:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < buff.size(); i++)
    value += buff.removeFirst().toString();
```

and

```java
value = new String((char[]) buff.toArray(new char[buff.size()]));
```

Comment: Go with the `BufferedReader` class... here there are too many memory allocations not to say that reading a file character by character is **really** slow

Comment: A LinkedList seems like a very cumbersome choice. Is there a good reason to use this, rather than, say, StringBuilder?

Comment: Also, note that the for loop will only add half the characters into the list. You should use `while (!buff.isEmpty())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing this you should write a benchmark. Take a look at [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) to understand how to write a benchmark with [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Your `for` loop would be inefficient as you are concatenating 1-letter `String`s using `+` operator. This leads to creation and immediate throwing away intermediate `String` objects. You should use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) if you plan to concatenate in a loop.

The second option should use a zero-length array as per [Arrays of Wisdom of the Ancients](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) article which dives into internal details of the JVM:

```
value = new String((char[]) buff.toArray(new char[0]));
```

Comment: Of course, you could then just use the StringBuilder to accumulate the  characters and eliminate the LinkedList entirely.

Comment: You can't call `toArray(new char[0])` on a `LinkedList`.